# HTML Canvas: Multiple getContext plotting at same time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm building a tool using websockets which allows multiple users to "draw" on each others' canvases. The user draws on a canvas, and an object containing mousedown/mouseup events and coordinates is pushed to other users instantaneously. This is then plotted on their canvases, which gives the effect of having multiple users drawing in the same place.

It works as described: you can watch somebody draw something, then draw something which will appear within their canvas. The problem occurs when you draw at the same moment as somebody else.

For each user, it creates a new context for each user's canvas using:

```
oekaki['canvas'] = document.getElementById('canvas');
oekaki['ctx'][unique_user_id] = oekaki['canvas'].getContext("2d");
```

When you draw at the same moment as another user, the canvases madly draw lines between your and their coordinates, despite it using the different contexts.

Why is this the case? Do I have to do something else to accommodate multiple lines being plotted at once? Is it not possible to create multiple contexts in this way?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The HTML5 Canvas spec says](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-getcontext), for `getContext()`:

> If the getContext() method has already been invoked on this element
>   for the same contextId, return the same object as was returned that
>   time, and abort these steps. The additional arguments are ignored.

You don't have a different context per user, it's the same one.  The last path position is being altererd by each new event, and I'm guessing you're not using `beginPath` and `moveTo` to reset the path on each new event.  Try something like this instead:

```
// on some event, want to draw to (x, y) now:
var ctx = oekaki.canvas.getContext('2d');
var user = oekaki.user[unique_user_id];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(user.lastX, user.lastY);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
// ctx.strokeStyle = ..., ctx.stroke(), etc, etc...
user.lastX = x;
user.lastY = y;
```

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant. This worked immediately, and saved me from hours more of frustration. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is the same context your users are drawing onto. I suggest to collect the incoming drawing requests and combine it in one paint method that builds the canvas contents when appropriate.