# I want to fill canvas with rectangle of different colors, why this doesn't work?It is filled with only one color

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCan");
var color = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'black', 'brown'];
var ctx = [];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
       ctx[i] = c.getContext("2d");
       ctx[i].fillStyle = color[i];
};
ctx[0].fillRect(0, 0, 100, 150);
ctx[1].fillRect(100, 0, 100, 150);
ctx[2].fillRect(200, 0, 100, 150);
ctx[3].fillRect(300, 0, 100, 150); 

ctx[4].fillRect(0, 150, 100, 150);
ctx[5].fillRect(100, 150, 100, 150);
ctx[6].fillRect(200, 150, 100, 150);
ctx[7].fillRect(300, 150, 100, 150);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCan" width="400px" height="300px" style="border:2px solid green">
Your browser does not support canvas
</canvas>
```

Comment: Aren't you overriding the  `fillStyle` and `fillRect` again and again for the same `div`.? Thats the reason it contains the last value from for loop, `fillStyle` that is 'brown', and similar case is for `fillRect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417318/html-canvas-multiple-getcontext-plotting-at-same-time).Subsequent getContext call would return the same object.Perhaps below mod closely matches your requirement

```
var c =               document.getElementById("myCan");
var color = ['red', 'blue', 'orange',  'green', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'black',  'brown'];
var ctx = [];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
   ctx[i] = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx[i].beginPath(); 
   ctx[i].fillStyle = color[i];
   if(i<4)ctx[i].fillRect(i*100, 0, 100, 150);
   if(i>=4)ctx[i].fillRect((i-4)*100, 150, 100, 150);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var color = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'black', 'brown', 'silver', 'chocolate'];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
    ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
    if(i < color.length /2){
       ctx.fillRect(i*100,0,100, 200);
    }else{
       ctx.fillRect((i-5)*100, 200, 100, 200);
    }
}
```