# Reverse image at end of animation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to re-create the bouncing ball effect but with an arrow.
When the arrow gets to the right wall it points left and come back until it reach the left wall and then point right again. Within a continuous loop.

I'm fairly new to JS and animation. Any help would be appreciated.

So far I have the arrow work fine back and forth, but doesn't reverse/flip when hitting the wall.

Thank you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>  

 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400" style="border: solid;   border-color: black;"></canvas>      
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var context;
        var dx = 1;
        var w3;
        var ctx;
        var img;

        function setCanvas() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

            if (canvas.getContext) {
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                img = new Image();

                img.onload = function (e) {                       

                    draw();
                }

                img.src = '/rightArrow2.png';
                w3 = img.width;

                draw();
            }
        }

        var startPos = 200;
        var endPos = 100;

        var x = 100;
        var y = 10;
        function draw() {

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);

            x += dx;

            if (x < endPos || x > startPos) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');                   
                var img2 = new Image();
                img2.src = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL(); 

                 var w4 = img2.width;
                ctx2.save();
                ctx2.translate(-w4, 0);
                ctx2.scale(-1, 1);
                ctx2.drawImage(img2, x , y);
                ctx2.restore();                  

                dx = -dx;
            }
            setTimeout(draw, 15);
        }
        setCanvas();
    }
    </script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the approach you are trying to use, but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8417932/6854845) a canvas cannot have multiple 2d contexts.
If you are trying to use a separate context to manipulate the image then you could create a separate, hidden canvas, and create a context on that canvas.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var context;
var dx= 4;
var dy=4;
var y=150;
var x=10;
function draw(){
 context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
 context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
 context.closePath();
 context.fill();
 if( x<0 || x>300)
 dx=-dx;
 if( y<0 || y>300)
  dy=-dy;
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;
 }
setInterval(draw,10);
```

```css
<!--
body { background-color:#ededed; font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

#container { width:600px; margin:0 auto; }
#myCanvas { background:#fff; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; }
#nav { display:block; width:100%; text-align:center; }
#nav li { display:block; font-weight:bold; line-height:21px; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff; width:100px; height:21px; padding:5px; margin:0 10px; background:#e0e0e0; border:1px solid #ccc; -moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px; border-radius:4px; float:left; }
#nav li a { color:#000; display:block; text-decoration:none; width:100%; height:100%; }
-->
```

```html
<div id="container">
 
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="http://sixrevisions.com/html/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/">View Tutorial</a></li>
<li><a href="http://sixrevisions.com/html/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/#comments">Post Comment</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no problem doing the animation, my problem is reversing/flip the arrow when it hit the wall, it has to point in the direction it is going. The ball doesn't have to do that. It's always the same ball no matter the direction.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Tried to make it work on JSFiddle but the link from PostImage wouldn't work. Base64 image would only show outside of the canvas. Jon came up with a solution and it's resolved. Thank you everyone. Roger

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your draw() function with this:

```
     function draw() {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        if (dx > 0) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        }
        else {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(x + img.width, y);
            ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            ctx.restore();
        }

        x += dx;

        if (x < endPos || x > startPos) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        setTimeout(draw, 15);

    }
```